# The number of adverbs in a sentence

Tags: adverbs

I wrote

> These wrappers can be generated automatically by a wrapper induction method or **semi-automatically** by the aid of the user **visually** or **in a programming language**.

There are multiple adverbs in the second clause that may overlap each other. How can I write such a sentence?

Answer (score 1):

You could try

> These wrappers can be generated automatically by a wrapper induction method or **with user assistance** either manual/visual or via a script or program.

It's a bit clunky, yet avoids repeating "automatically".  I am sure you can improve upon it.